# Viewchild returning Undefined

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular 6, and attempting to get access to the dom element in order to execute stripe elements. I'm using @Viewchild to get a hold of the dom element, and I keep getting undefined.

I tried blitz and I'm getting the same result. What am I doing wrong here ?

P.s I've read the other stackoverflow questions regarding this, and I'm not using *ngIf on the element or a parent element.

EDIT: oh I forgot the blitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lamiqb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Post your code ..what you tried..

Comment: Sorry I forgot to paste the blitz, updated now.

Comment: you need `<div #ibanelm id="ibanelm"></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to access the DOM element using View Child. You need to use Template Reference Variable. Here is the stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-iqupkt

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change from id to **#ibanelm**

here is example,

```
<div #ibanelm></div>
```

updated  [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x6zwfu?file=src/app/app.component.html)